# Continue the calling the method based on output in java

Tags: java, string, if-statement, while-loop

I have a very basic java question.  I have a if loop checking a condition if its true, then it calls a methodA (string test) , now this methodA returns ouput string "test".so i need to keep calling this methodA, until it keeps stops returning output string contains "test".

```
if (sample.contains("test")
{
output = callmethodA(sample)

system.out.println("return as test"+output="**test** is available here")
}
```

here if output contains text as "test". i need to call this method again methodA(sample) until the output doesnt contain text as "test"

how to achieve this in java? please advise. Thanks.

I have a very basic java question.  I have a if loop checking a condition if its true, then it calls a methodA (string test) , now this methodA returns ouput string "test".so i need to keep calling this methodA, until it keeps stops returning output string contains "test".

Comment: here is the sample code am trying  
    if (sample.contains("test")
    {
    output = callmethodA(sample)
    
    system.out.println("return as test"+output="**test** is available here")
    }

Comment: Why not use a `do while` loop for that?

Comment: An `if` is not a loop. It's just a decision point. If you want a loop you need either `while` or `for` - in your case, `while` is probably the right one.

Comment: Thanks... my first attempt was do while , but i made a very silly mistake of passing the same output again and again... after posting the ques realized when debuggin... Thanks for all your support. Appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you would like to archive:

```
do {
  system.out.println("return as test"+output="**test** is available here")
}
while (!sample.contains("test"));
output = callmethodA(sample)
```

The while checks the conndition and will run until sample contains test after that it will call your function